# Why is $\vec{v}$ constant according to Kepler's laws?

Tags: newtonian-gravity

I was looking up how Newton derived his Law of Gravitation  and came across [this website](http://www.relativitycalculator.com/Newton_Universal_Gravity_Law.shtml) which derives the law from Kepler's laws.

It starts off with Kepler's second law and says that:

$$\frac{\omega}{v} = \frac{s}{r}$$

Where $\vec{v}$ is the linear velocity, $\vec{\omega}$ is the angular velocity, $s$ is the distance travelled in time $t$, and $\vec{r}$ is the radius.

However, what it says is that $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{\omega}$ are constant. I understand why $\vec{\omega}$ is constant, but why $\vec{v}$?

Comment: I assume you are asking why $v=|\vec{v}|$ is constant.  $\vec{v}$, of course, is not constant.  The assumption in the derivation is that the planet is executing uniform circular motion.

Comment: @garyp Well I assume that's the case, but the link says that $\vec{v}$ specifically is constant. Similarly, on the diagram it shows that the line drawn for $vec{v}$ stays pointing in the same direction as the planet orbits.

Comment: The parallel $\vec{v}$s are there, I think, to help define $\vec{\omega}$.    Yeah, that website has problems.    Maybe you should find another.

Comment: @garyp It's fine, simply the definition that $a = v^2/r$ is enough :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of the derivation is the centripetal acceleration. I guess I am not sure about this derivation for the ratio has a distance over a distance on the right, but angular velocity divided by velocity on the right. It does not make sense with units.

I put in a diagram similar to the diagram on the website. The idea is with similar triangles. Without a detailed geometry proof of the sort taught in high school the yellow and blue triangles are similar. This holds with the idea that the $\Delta r$ is small so the arc length formula works so $\Delta r~=~\theta r$ and $\Delta v~=~\theta v$. This gives the ratio
$$
\frac{\Delta v}{v}~=~\frac{\Delta r}{r}.
$$
Now using $\Delta v~=~a\Delta t$ and $\Delta r~=~r\Delta t$ we have
$$
\frac{a}{v}~=~\frac{v}{r}~\rightarrow~a~=~\frac{v^2}{r}.
$$
This is the standard derivation result for centripetal acceleration with circular motion.

For circular motion we have $v~=~\omega r$. For circular motion the radius $r$ is constant and so if the velocity is constant is means the angular velocity $\omega$ must be constant. We could have done the above derivation with $\theta~=~\omega\Delta t$ so the ratio becomes
$$
\frac{\Delta v}{v}~=~\omega\Delta t,
$$
and it is pretty easy to get $a~=~\omega^2 r$.

[image]

Comment: I suppose the website defined $\omega = \Delta v$ and $s = \Delta r$...

Comment: But that seems to equate angular velocity with units $sec^{-1}$ with velocity that has units $m/sec$.